# RSpec pass validation test, which should be failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have a `Company` model with `attr_accessor :administrator`, so when user creates company, he also need to fill some fields for administrator of this company. I'm trying to test, that he fill all fields correctly.

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :administrator

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :administrator, presence: true, if: :administrator_is_valid?

  private

  def administrator_is_valid?
    administrator[:name].present? and
        administrator[:phone].present? and
        administrator[:email].present? and
        administrator[:password].present? and
        administrator[:password_confirmation].present? and
        administrator[:password] == administrator[:password_confirmation]
  end

end
```

`company_spec.rb` is:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Company do

  it 'is valid with name and administrator' do
    company = Company.new(name: 'Company',
    administrator: {
        name: nil,
        email: nil,
        phone: nil,
        password: 'password',
        password_confirmation: ''
    })

    expect(company).to be_valid
  end

end
```

So, as you see, I have a lot of mistakes in validation test, but RSpec pass it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you didn't construct your validation properly. See, `if: administrator_is_valid?` will return false for your test, telling Rails to skip this validation rule.

I suggest you drop using the presence validator in favor of using `administrator_is_valid?` method as a validation method, because after all, if the administrator is valid then it is present. The code should look like this

```
validate :administrator_is_valid?

private

def administrator_is_valid?
    (administrator[:name].present? and
        administrator[:phone].present? and
        administrator[:email].present? and
        administrator[:password].present? and
        administrator[:password_confirmation].present? and
        administrator[:password] == administrator[:password_confirmation]) or
    errors.add(:administrator, 'is not valid')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could clean up your code like this:

```
validate :administrator_is_valid?

private

def administrator_is_valid?
  if administrator_cols_present? && administrator_passwords_match?
    true
  else
    errors.add(:administrator, 'is not valid')
  end
end

def administrator_cols_present?
  %w(name phone email password password_confirmation).all? do |col|
    administrator[col.to_sym].present? # or use %i() instead of to_sym
  end
end

def administrator_passwords_match?
  administrator[:password] == administrator[:password_confirmation]
end
```

Another improvement might be to move your `administrator` to a struct, then call `valid?` on the object.

```
admin = Struct.new(cols) do
  def valid?
    cols_present? && passwords_match?
  end

  def cols_present?
    cols.values.all? { |col| col.present? }
  end

  def passwords_match?
    cols[:password] == cols[:password_confirmation]
  end
end
```

Then:

```
validate :administrator_is_valid?

def admin_struct
  @admin_struct ||= admin.new(administrator)
end

def administrator_is_valid?
  errors.add(:administrator, 'is not valid') unless admin_struct.valid?
end
```